# Azure Mobile App Not Available Among Existing Apps

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service

Back in March 2015, [Microsoft announced that "Azure Mobile Apps" are replacing "Azure Mobile Services."](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Azure-App-Service-Mobile-Apps-with-Kirill-Gavrylyuk)  A few days ago, I spotted [the documentation explaining how to create an Azure Mobile App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started/). I followed the doc and successfully got my "TestDroid" mobile app service running locally.  However, I cannot publish the app to Azure from Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

To publish my "TestDroid" app, I right-clicked on the project and selected "publish."

[image]

This dialogue is already the "first sign of trouble."  Technically my Mobile App service does not match any of the categories shown in the above dialogue.  Still, because Web Apps and Mobile Services have been merged into one, the best choice is "Microsoft Azure Web Apps."  So that is the choice I made...

Unfortunately, Visual Studio 2015 CE does not show my already-provisioned "TestDroid" app as an option:

[image]

However, I know that it exists because I created it a day earlier, per the instructions, and it does appear in a resource group blade on the Azure portal:

[image]

Also, in the Visual Studio "Server Explorer" I can see the "TestDroid" service:

[image]

The Server Explorer entry for "Mobile Services" is empty, but in this case I expect it to be empty because, as already stated, creating a "Mobile Service" is now considered the old way, and creating a "Mobile App" is the new way.

I'm guessing this is merely a glitch in preview material, but I would like to know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 6):

I got this working.  In the end I simply visited the Azure blade for my "TestDroid" mobile app, and selected "get publish profile".  I used the "import" option on the VS 2015 publish dialogue to import the publish profile.

The original MS instructions did not mention that this slightly-round-about approach was necessary, so I did not assume at first to try it.

All is well that ends well. :)